# I want to code the boolean opposite input?

Tags: javascript

How do I code a function  that takes in any input and returns the boolean opposite of the provided input. This is what I already have.

```
function not(color) {
    let red = color
    return color===false;
}
not(a,b);
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do. This is unclear.

Comment: The question is not clear. But if the input value is NOT a boolean, there is no "boolean opposite" concept for this variable. 
If you compare a string with a boolean, like "string" === true is always to be false.

Comment: As mentioned before this question needs improvement, elaborate better, also noticed you have `not(a,b)` are you trying to compare two colors? and return true if they are not? Once you have your question figured out we'll be happy to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but if you want to just get the boolean opposite of a variable you could do something like this. I don't think you need a function.

```
 var color = true
 color = !color
```

This will change "color" to become false

Comment: Sadly, the question is unclear and attempting to reply will just lead to frustration, thing is that if we notice at the end he has a `not(a,b)` which may imply he is actually trying to compare two colors and figuring out if they are opposites?